# IE floated elements doesn't show perfectly

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I'm using [Superfish jQuery plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) to create multi level drop down menu. But I've some terrible problems in `IE6/7`. the `li`s are floated to right and display in one line in Firefox (no problem), but in IE, the first one (which doesn't contain a link (`a`) tag) shows at right and the others show at left (in 2/3 lines)
a piece of the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Emhj4/8/

What should I do?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have `display: block` for your `A` element of top list. You just need to remove this and add that property for your other 'menulevel' element. Something like this:

```
.menulevel1 a{color:#fff;position:relative;}

.menulevel1 li ul a{display:block;width:100%;background:#ccc;border:1px solid #000;padding:4px 5px;}
```

[Live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Emhj4/14/)